# should TCP_KEEPIDLE be lower than TCP_KEEPINTVL?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ubuntu, tcp

I am working with sockets in C (on Ubuntu) and I want to test some options with `setsockopt`.

When I wanted to test the *Keep Alive* options: `TCP_KEEPIDLE` and `TCP_KEEPINTVL` (both from `IPPROTO_TCP` family), I noticed this weird behavior :

**Expected behavior**
When I set `TCP_KEEPIDLE` as 1 (second) and `TCP_KEEPINTVL` as 3, the *Keep Alive* probes start to be sent after 1 second of idle time, and then every 3 seconds.

**Unexpected behavior**
But when I set `TCP_KEEPIDLE` as 3, and `TCP_KEEPINTVL` as 1, the probes are also sent every 3 seconds (instead of 1), so the interval is the idle time instead of the one I specificaly set.

Is there any spec or doc saying that `TCP_KEEPIDLE` is always lower than or equal to `TCP_KEEPINTVL`, or is it a bug ?

Thanks.

Comment: Whatever may be the case please multiply these timers by at least ten. They are ridiculously short.

Comment: This is not the issue. With Wireshark, I can clearly see the timing, and the difference is really significant. Keep in mind that this is not for actual purpose, only for testing the options.

Comment: Is the remote host sending ack to keepalive? I'm fighting against the same problem and I suspect that, in case of your described unexpected behavior, acks to keepalive are considered socket activity.

Comment: @MirkoBanchi That was nearly 4 years ago, so I don't really remember much. IIRC, the ACK was indeed send instantaneously. The socket may consider the Keepalive probe to be activity, thus resetting the idle timer, then waiting for the time set with `TCP_KEEPIDLE` to pass. That would explain the 3 seconds interval instead of 1, but the doc seem too shallow about the interactions between the flags. I guess I would have had to delve into Unix's code, but I don't dare say that I could understand it.

Answer (score 3):

Following is my observation

**TCP_KEEPIDLE comes into picture when connection is idle**.
TCP_KEEPIDLE is used to send keepalive probes when connection is idle. Here, Idle connection means no data is sent from client to server. So, if TCP_KEEPIDLE is set 120 seconds, then server will send keepalive probes to client after 120s.

**TCP_KEEPINTVL and TCP_KEEPCNT come into picture when connection broken**.
Now, let's assume connection has been broken due to network failure. Network failure can be produced by removing LAN cable at the client. Now, server will close the connection after "TCP_KEEPINTVL * TCP_KEEPCNT". So, if TCP_KEEPINTVL is 75 (which is default value on linux) and TCP_KEEPCNT is 9 (which is default value on linux, server will send 9 probes each after 75 seconds and close the connection is there is no response.

---

**Relation between TCP_KEEPIDLE and TCP_KEEPINTVL**

In **Qnx OS**, I observed that there is not relation between TCP_KEEPIDLE and TCP_KEEPINTVL. TCP_KEEPIDLE can be lower than TCP_KEEPINTVL.

In **Linux OS**, I observed that there is a relation between TCP_KEEPIDLE and TCP_KEEPINTVL. TCP_KEEPIDLE can not be lower than TCP_KEEPINTVL. And I think this is a bug.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write your answer. However, this does not answer the question. The issue I have is the relation between `TCP_KEEPIDLE` and `TCP_KEEPINTVL`. If you read the comments on my question, you can see that the prime suspect here is that the keep-alive probes are considered activity, thus resetting the idle time, making the `TCP_KEEPINTVL` useless. But I cannot find any documentation or source code on that, so I cannot plan things on assumptions.

Comment: I have updated my comment. And I believe that scenario that you have mentioned is a bug.